# How to refer to a footnote?

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes

How do I refer to a footnote?  For example, if is constructed like this

```
blah blah blah blah\footnote{blah blah \label{footnote_1}}
```

would you refer to it using this line?

```
As mentioned in note \ref{footnote_1}.
```

Comment: Yes and that works. It is simple and requires no additional packages.

Answer (score 43):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\begin{document}

argument of the footnote command that is being 
labelled\footnote{Note text\label{fnlabel}}
potato head\footref{fnlabel}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\ref{...}` instead of `\footref{...}` if you want the number to be printed inline rather than as superscript. Also, `\pageref{...}` works to refer to the page the footnote is printed on.

Answer (score 11):

It also works with the all-powerful [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en) (instead of `footmisc`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
Here is some real nondescript text\footnote{What a qualifier\label{xxx}}

Then I can refer later to \cref{xxx} (\Cpageref{xxx})
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! In contradistinction to footmisc this solution works with hyperref.

Comment: As a side note, `hyperref` can work with `footmisc` if you load `hyperref` with the option `[hyperfootnotes=false]`, which turns off links to footers, or load `hyperref` after `footmisc`. But I agree, `cleveref` is much more clever :)