# Cross-references to footnotes when there are multiple footnotes

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, reledmac, ledmac

I am using multiple footnotes (`\footnoteA`, `\footnoteB` and `\footnoteC`) in a complicated text. I need to refer to some of them. I therefore tried the package
`footmisc`, but when I have a `\label{}` within a fn. and later refer to it with a `\ref{}`, all that I am getting is the number of the section or subsection, not that of the footnote.
E.g.:

```
"See also fn \ref{abhiman3}"
```

leads to

```
"See also fn 12.10.3.1.4" (this is the number of the subsubsection).
```

I also tried being more precise, i.e. `\label{fn:abhiman3}` and `\ref{fn:abhiman3}`, but the same result follows. `\footref{}` instead of `\ref{}` changes the section number to superscript, but still does not deliver what I want, namely the footnote number.

I tried the `cref` package, but it does not compile (possibly because of a conflict with another package).

Any alternative suggestion? Thanks!

UPDATE MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

[…]
\usepackage[noeledmac]{ledmac}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

Copyist's mangala.\footnoteC{Auspicious verse.\label{mangala}}

Author's mangala\footnoteC{See fn. \ref{mangala}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if you use `\pageref{}` instead of `\ref{}`? This is not going to completely solve your problem, but it would be easier to find a footnote if you know the page number rather than the subsection. EDIT: I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167380/how-to-refer-to-a-footnote), it might help.

Comment: What package(s) are you using for the multiple footnotes? Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass... ` to `\end{document}` that we can compile and that shows your problem. How do you get multiple footnotes? How do you refer to them?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!
—Yes, \pageref{} would help, but is not ideal.

Comment: If I compile your example with `\usepackage{reledmac}`, instead of `ledmac` (and even without `footmisc`), I get the desired reference: number of the `footnoteC`, not of the section. `reledmac` is the "grandchild" of `ledmac`, which is nowadays deprecated. `reledmac` is actively maintained, has a variety of tools for referencing footnotes, has `hyperref` support and is very flexible.  Unless there's something specific holding you back, I very warmly recommend migrating to `reledmac`! (See the [migration guide](https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/migration.pdf)).

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your code for readability and have added tags for (re)ledmac, as this could get more attention to the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Marquinho, it works in the MWE and also in my book if I take out a section with a critical edition with multiple apparati. I will try to see how to obtain multiple apparati with reledmac. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it is probably best to switch from `ledmac` to `reledmac`, which should solve this problem.

However, if for some reason you need to stay with `ledmac`, you can redefine the `\footnoteC` command to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`, i.e., put this in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoteC}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{footnoteC}%
  \protected@xdef\@thefnmarkC{\thefootnoteC}%
  \@footnotemarkC
  \vfootnoteC{C}{#1}\m@mmf@prepare}
\makeatother
```

(If you need to do the same for, e.g., `\footnoteB`, the code is the same except with `B`s where this definition has uppercase `C`s.)

Comment: Thank you! 
I am now moving to reledmac (thanks to Marquinho again for suggesting it). Advice for people with a similar problem: The reledmac and footmisc packages can work together, but they must be in the correct sequence (footmisc evoked in the preamble before reledmac).

Comment: @elisafreschi: Glad that the migration to reledmac is working for you :) Regardless, did you try frabjous's suggestion with your old code (f.i. your MWE that used `ledmac`), and did it solve the problem? If so, please consider upvoting and marking their answer as "accepted" (the green checkmark at the top left) as a reference for future users.

Comment: @elisafreschi: can you confirm that frabjous's answer works in the specific case that you asked about? If so, please do mark their answer as "accepted"! Thanks :)