# Am I using citations the right way?

Tags: biblatex, formatting, citing

I want to have citation as footnotes, for this I use `\footfullcite`. For citation in the text, I use `\cite`. I just discovered the `style=authoryear-icomp` does the `ibidem` replacement for identical citations. But it doesn't seem to work.

I want to have full citations in the notes, the `authoryear` for in-text citations, and the `ibidem` for identical citations.

What am I missing or using wrong?

Here my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
        bibencoding=utf-8,
        natbib=true,
        style=authoryear-icomp,
        backend=biber,
        url=false,
        doi=false,
        isbn=false,
        eprint=false,
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/home/enrico/Università/uni_bib.bib}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
```

Comment: Should "ibid." be also in the footnote cite?

Comment: I would say that generally speaking, If you find yourself using `\fullcite` and `\footfullcite` more than a couple of times in your document, there probably is more elegant way to resolve things. It's not wrong per se, but unusual. In your use case it's not clear for me why you use two different kinds of citations (in-text vs. footnotes) and when you would want to use which kind of citation.

Comment: `\fullcite` and `\footfullcite` operate "outside" the normal citation tracking. They do not respond to most cite-style-specific settings like "ibid.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you like:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{uni_bib.bib}
    @article{author,
        author = "A. Author",
        title = "A Title",
        journal = "A Journal",
        volume = "1",
        number = "2",
        year = "2023"
    }
    @article{buthor,
        author = "B. Buthor",
        title = "B Title",
        journal = "B Journal",
        volume = "3",
        number = "4",
        year = "2022"
    }    
    @article{cuthor,
        author = "C. Cuthor",
        title = "C Title",
        journal = "C Journal",
        volume = "4",
        number = "5",
        year = "2021"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} no more needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
%\PassOptionsToPackage{ <---- Why this?
\usepackage[
    bibencoding=utf-8,
    natbib=true,
    style=authoryear-ibid,
    backend=biber,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    eprint=false,
    ]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
      {\usedriver
          {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
          {\thefield{entrytype}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

 \DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
   {\citetrackerfalse\usebibmacro{prenote}}
   {\usebibmacro{cite}}
   {\multicitedelim}
   {\usebibmacro{postnote}\citetrackertrue}
 
\addbibresource{uni_bib.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}% better loaded at last

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
    cite: \cite{author}
    cite again: \cite{author}
    foot full cite: \footfullcite{buthor}
    foot full cite again: \footfullcite{buthor}
    cite: \cite{cuthor}
    foot full cite first: \footfullcite{cuthor}
    foot full cite second: \footfullcite{cuthor}
    cite: \cite{author}
    foot full cite third: \footfullcite{cuthor}
    foot full cite fouth: \footfullcite{cuthor}
    \newpage
    cite: \cite{author}
    cite again: \cite{author}
    foot full cite: \footfullcite{buthor}
    foot full cite again: \footfullcite{buthor}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image]
[image]

Page 2:

[image]
[image]

Bibliography:

[image]

Comment: This is what I get with my setup, but I want `ibid.` when there is the same citation on the same page. This should be done by `style=authoryear-icomp`, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, I want the full citation on the first note

Comment: @enrico223 There is "ibid." when the citation is repeated. Do you want it also in the footnotes?

Comment: Yes, I just need it in the footnotes. Sorry I didn't explain myself.

Comment: @enrico223 Should the ibidem of `\cite` be independent of the one of `\footfullcite`? That is, in the text, ibidem as is now in my example, and in the footnote, ibidem if the previous footnote citation is equal, even if there are other in-text citations between two footnote citations?

Comment: I want ibidem if the previous footnote citation is equal. I *do not* want ibidem for in-text citations

Comment: @enrico223 See my renewed answer. Is it what you like?

Comment: Marked as accepted. Also, IDK if I should open another question or not, so I'll ask here: is there a way to point to just full cite the first time I cite a paper, and then point to that note in subsequent footnotes? Something like "See note X".

Comment: @enrico223 Thank you for accepting my answer! If you want to do it automatically, it's better you open another question. If you want to do it "manually", see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167380/101651.