# Footnotes starting at 0, not 1

Tags: footnotes, moderncv, footmisc

I've searched the site, and ended up using `footmisc` with `moderncv` to use footnotes, but the footnotes start at 0 ... not 1. I would like something like a dagger, but none of those solutions on the site worked. At the very least, I'd like it to start at 1.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=0.63in]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{5pt}
\usepackage{import}
\nopagenumbers{}

% personal data
\name{}{}
\phone[mobile]{}                   
\email{}    
\social{}
\homepage{}         


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{footmisc}

\begin{document}

    \cventry{}{}{}{}{}
    {       \textbf{Relevant Courses Completed by Summer 2025:} Algorithms and Complexity\footref{class_disclaimer}, Programming Languages\footref{class_disclaimer}, Computer Networking, Real Analysis, Abstract Algebra\footref{class_disclaimer}, Digital Circuit Design \& Implementation, Compiler Construction, Probability Theory, Computer Security
    }

\enlargethispage{\footskip}
\footnotetext{\label{class_disclaimer}Enrolled Fall 2025}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just use `\stepcounter{footnote}` and `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}`

Comment: Could you please provide a MWE @Stephen to show how to use this?

Comment: Add these two commands in your document preamble.

Comment: Normally, `\footnote` or `\footnotemark` increment the footnote counter (using `\refstepcounter`).  One wonders what the `\label` is hooking up to..

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to increment the footnote @JohnKormylo ? What do you mean about the bad usage of `\label`?

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167380/how-to-refer-to-a-footnote) was what I was trying to do.

Comment: I see. I achieved a rough fix by using `\setcounter{#}` before a `\footnotetext{\label{}}` whose symbol I wanted to be different than a prior, and referencing with `\footref{label}`

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you're instructing me to do. I'm definitely interested in learning the correct way.

Comment: It turns out that `\footnotetext` sets `\@currentlabel` after all, which is needed when the footnote number is passed as an optional argument..

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `\footref` command improperly. You need to have at least one proper footnote containing the label and then use `\footref` for all the identical footnote markers you need. You can change the set of symbols used by creating a new set with `\DefineFNsymbols*`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{black}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=0.63in]{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{5pt}
\usepackage{import}
\nopagenumbers{}

% personal data
\name{}{}
\phone[mobile]{}                   
\email{}    
\social{}
\homepage{}         


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\DefineFNsymbols*{cv}{\dagger\ddagger\S\P\|%
    {\dagger\dagger}{\ddagger\ddagger}}
\setfnsymbol{cv}

\begin{document}

    \cventry{}{}{}{}{}
    {       \textbf{Relevant Courses Completed by Summer 2025:} Algorithms and Complexity\footnotemark, Programming Languages\footref{class_disclaimer}, Computer Networking, Real Analysis, Abstract Algebra\footref{class_disclaimer}, Digital Circuit Design \& Implementation, Compiler Construction, Probability Theory, Computer Security
    }

\enlargethispage{\footskip}
\footnotetext{\label{class_disclaimer}Enrolled Fall 2025}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]
[image: footnote]

Comment: This does not work for me. Gives `??` result or no output.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the `\DefineFNsymbols*` command when using `pdflatex`. The document compiles fine with `lualatex`. With `pdflatex` remove the code to define and set the symbols, and add `\setcounter{footnote}{1}` to the preamble. Since it's using references you'll need to compile twice to get all of the markers right.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't get the dagger to work. Only `*` symbols.

Comment: Did you add the `\setcounter{footnote}{1}`?

Comment: `\setcounter{footnote}{2}` works. Do you know how I can make it so that there is a different symbol for each footnote label that I create?